# Move component to another product in Bugzilla?

Tags: bugzilla

We have two products, A and B, that should have been one product all along.

Each product has a number of components.

I want to be able to move the components of B so that they will belong to A.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A not so easy way is to

- Create the same components under Product A.
- On trying to delete components from product B, Bugzilla will prompt you to transfer the already existing bugs under those components
- Reassign those bugs to respective components in Product A
- Delete components from product B, after the transfer

And you are all set!!

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know about the bug transfer, which makes this a good workable solution for me.  There is just a handful of components to transfer.